# class member as reference to another: crash in assignment operator

Tags: c++, reference, class-members

I have a class `Bar` with references to inside of one of its members (`Bar::foo`):

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

struct Foo{
    int x, y;
};

struct Bar{
    Foo foo;
    int &x, &y;
    Bar(): x(foo.x), y(foo.y){}
    // copy constructor and assignment operator
    Bar(const Bar& other): foo(other.foo), x(foo.x), y(foo.y){}
    Bar& operator=(const Bar& other){ foo=other.foo; return *this; }
};

int main(void){
    std::vector<Bar> a, b;
    Bar p; p.x=0; p.y=0;
    a.push_back(p);
    std::copy(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin());
}
```

Compiling with `g++` (without any special options), I get crash in the assignment operator. Why?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400b29 in Bar::operator= (this=0x0, other=...) at ref2.cpp:14
14      Bar& operator=(const Bar& other){ foo=other.foo; return *this; }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400b29 in Bar::operator= (this=0x0, other=...) at ref2.cpp:14
#1  0x00000000004016a0 in std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<Bar*, Bar*> (
__first=0x405010, __last=0x405030, __result=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:329
#2  0x000000000040148d in std::__copy_move_a<false, Bar*, Bar*> (__first=0x405010, __last=0x405030, __result=0x0)
at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:384
#3  0x0000000000401157 in std::__copy_move_a2<false, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bar*, std::vector<Bar, std::allocator<Bar> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bar*, std::vector<Bar, std::allocator<Bar> > > > (__first=..., __last=..., 
__result=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:422
#4  0x0000000000400cc0 in std::copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bar*, std::vector<Bar, std::allocator<Bar> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Bar*, std::vector<Bar, std::allocator<Bar> > > > (__first=..., __last=..., __result=...)
at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:454
#5  0x00000000004009f4 in main () at ref2.cpp:21
```

Comment: I don't think unnamed structs are allowed in C++... Anyway, this looks like horrible, horrible code, which totally violates the spirit of C++ and OO.

Comment: @KerrekSB: you're formally right, g++ refuses the code with `-pedantic`. Imageine a name there.

Comment: Can you imagine I posted an answer and accept it? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh, I had the idea that they were allowed in C++11, but it seems only anonymous unions are. Thanks for that note.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - one could argue the typical OO style is horrible :) I don't see anything too bad on his code.

Answer (score 4):

**Is this legal?**

No, because anonymous structs are not legal. If you name it, it will invoke undefined behaviour *unless* `foo` is correctly initialized first (particularly you can't read the `x` and `y` members if you initialized `data`).

**Once I fix all that, what other problems will this cause?**

Well, first, having any kind of reference members inhibits the generation of an assignment operator. That may or may not be important to you. And then, the compiler generated copy constructor will bite you: it just blindly copies all the members, ending with a copy of the `foo` member and the reference members referring the `foo` of the *original* object. If this original object has a shorter lifetime, bad things will happen. You may want to write a copy constructor, or consider alternative designs without reference members.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer, you're probably on the right track. I added copy ctor and assignment operator to the class, similar to what I have in the code which crashes for me. Does it provide correct semantics for copying?

Comment: It seems ok to me. You should do some more debugging: there's something else going on. Try to isolate the same problem in a small example, to see what is the source.

Comment: I isolated the crash to a few lines of code and put it into the original post, including backtrace from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your union members first, or it's IIRC undefined behavior. Then you can init references to your union members as well.

Comment: Creating reference to unitialized data is not UB, as long as the reference is not being actually accessed (correct me if I am wrong; like creating pointer to uninitialized chunk of memory is not UB; you can fill that chunk of memory with data later, before using the pointer)

Comment: you should be - but your code doesn't seem to fill it anywhere anyway.

Comment: The code is just defining data structures and some operations on them, independent of the data which it will hold when used.